# How to use ternary conditional operator with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom, innerhtml, conditional-operator

How to use ternary operator inside element.innerHTML correctly?

```js
el.innerHTML = {
  `<span>title</span>
    ${menuOpened &&
       `<div>
         <span>opened</span>
       </div>`
    }
  `
}
```

Comment: what's the condition, `menuOpened === true`?

Comment: you properly looking into a `ternary conditional operator` such as: `element.innerHTML = (condition) ? 'string for true' : 'string for false'`. As side-note: `innerHTML` should not be used. It is slow (DOM needs to be re-parsed) and poses a security issue (XSS-injection).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use a string template inside another ` inside string template. I might be wrong but I would work around it using other quotes.

```js
el = {};
menuOpened = true
el.innerHTML =
  `<span>title</span>
    ${menuOpened && '<div><span>opened</span></div>' }
  `;
  
console.log(el)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course you can do it in one-liner template, but for readability of your code you can split it on multiple steps in classic way, check inline comments:

```js
// Set your must have html
let html = `<span>title</span>`;

// Pre-set condition for example purpose
const menuOpened = true;

// Append html if condition is true
if(menuOpened) html += `<div><span>opened</span></div>`;

// Then inner html
// For now we'll just console log it
console.log(html);
```

But in case you have more complex html and you need to insert data, not add it like in your case, then:

```js
// Pre-set condition for example purpose
const menuOpened = true;

// Set code for menu
const menu = menuOpened ? `<div><span>opened</span></div>` : '';

// Set your html template
const html = `<div><span>title</span>${menu}</div>`;

// Then inner html
// For now we'll just console log it
console.log(html);
```